# php location header redirect works even after output has started

Tags: redirect, php-7, php-7.2

I thought you couldn't redirect using `header('location:..` in php if you had already sent some output.  However, this test program works as (un)expected with the local server.

```
$ cat > index.php
Hello,
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== "/") {
  header('location: /');
  die();
}

?>
World!
```

and then I start the php local server like this

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

and then when I go to `http://localhost:8000/index.php?test=1` it redirects me to `http://localhost:8000`.

Why isn't it complaining that I have already sent output? is it something different about php 7?  Something different about modern browsers?  Something different about the demo server?  Or do I need to do something slightly different to get the error I got last time I used php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your script, and for me it reported back the expected "Cannot modify header" warning and only displayed "Hello,".

The main thing that could be different for you is the `output_buffering` variable in your php.ini - if it is not disabled, then it automatically buffers the output up to a certain size. So check if it is set to either "On" or something like 4096. The default value if Off, but there are a lot of sample configs where it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Now I also managerd to get the error just by starting the dev server like this`php -nS 0.0.0.0:8000`. from help `-n               No configuration (ini) files will be used`